# Runtime Exception in converting set to vector and vector to string in c++

Tags: c++

Hi I have just started learning c++ and i cant seem to make out why this code is giving me a runtime exception while converting a vector to set and set to vector. Please Help!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { cin >> v[i]; }
    set<int> s(v.begin(), v.end());
    vector<int> v2(s.begin(), s.end());

    if (v2.size() >= 2)
        cout << v2[1];
    else
        cout << "NO";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look on your `set` definition. You're creating a new set for only one value? What is your intention with this variable?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) as well as [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I am creating a set so that all the duplicate elements of the vector can be removed and sorted.Then im converting it to a vector so that  i can access the second element.

Comment: Regarding your current code, instead of the vector-set-vector conversion you might be interested to learn about the [standard algorithm functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) available, especially [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: As a side note, this code doesn't throw any exceptions.  segfault (which probably happens here) is not an exception in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong

```
vector<int > v; 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {cin>>v[i];}
```

Your vector is created at size zero, so `v[i]` is an out of bounds vector access whatever the value of `i`. Vectors don't grow just because you assign elements to them.

Two possible solutions

1) Create the vector at the right size to begin with

```
vector<int > v(n); // vector of size n
```

Or

2) Use `push_back` to add items to the back of the vector

```
vector<int > v; 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { int t; cin>>t; v.push_back(t); }
```

Comment: Yes got it Thank you so much!

Comment: I add that if you use `v.at(i)` an exception is thrown making the error more aparent.